# Why is __getitem__ not implemented by dask series?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dask

I am having trouble doing anything useful with a dask series object. After I manage to create one, I am unable to work with it at a level lower than the series object itself. In other words, I can compute it and load it into memory then get the data I want (`dseries.compute()['x']`), but ideally I would like something like this: `dseries['x'].compute()`, since for my actual application dseries.compute() will likely be too large for memory.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as ddf
import random

for i in range(5):
    pdseries = pd.Series({'x':random.randint(0,10),'y':random.randint(0,10),'z':random.randint(0,10)})
    pdseries.to_hdf(f'test{i}.hdf5','data',format='table')

dseries = ddf.read_hdf('test*.hdf5','data')

print(dseries['x'])
```

This raises a `NotImplementedError`. I suppose I would expect it to return some sort of dask object that, when computed, returned the data from the files.

Comment: Does `loc` work?

Comment: @mdurant Indeed it does. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `loc` in this case. 
You might be interested in proposing, or indeed implementing getitem for dask series, since the functionality already exists.

Comment: Thanks @mdurant. How might I go about proposing this?

Comment: Raise an issue at https://github.com/dask/dask/issues , or make your own pull request (fork the repo, start a new branch, push, and then make PR using the github interface), which would require tests.